# CSV file "unique ID" - reading and writing

Tags: c#, csv, unique-key

I'm trying to get my program to write a randomized unique number to a CSV file, I can write to the file but I'm having some issues with the reading/randomizing feature.

It should check my second column (1), for the OR number. If it exists keep randomizing, and if it doesn't exist write a new row to the CSV file.

Long story short: How do I compare my string (OR) to a column value ?

```
public string OR = string.Empty;

private void randomize()
{
    int Number;
    Random r = new Random();
    Number = r.Next(1, 5);
    OR = Convert.ToString(Number);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    randomize();

    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("Database.csv"));
    List<string> listA = new List<string>();
    List<string> listB = new List<string>();
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    // Keep randomizing until a new number has been found
        while (!reader.EndOfStream && values[1].ToString() == OR)
        {
            randomize();
            MessageBox.Show( OR + " WHILE");
        }
    // Write if number doesn't equal to a existing one
        if (values[1].ToString() != OR)
        {
            label1.Text = OR;
            MessageBox.Show( OR + " IF");
            //reader.Close();
            //reader.Dispose();
            //writeTo();
        }

}

public void writeTo()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Database.csv", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("hey" + "," + OR + "," + "test");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the significance or reason for needing a randomized and unique number?

Comment: @Shoe There is no specific reason for it to be randomized, I would just prefer it that way, but it has to be unique number as I'm using it for some PDF documents.

Comment: You are creating `Random` class each time and this by default uses seed from system clock so will give lots of same results. Create it once and use same instance

Comment: A good way to get unique numbers is to use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssffff");` If you don't have a random requirement I would use this as it's simpler.

Comment: @dkozl Wouldn't I have to press the button multiple times in order to get a result then(writing to the file)? Excuse me if the answer is obvious but i'm still really new at C#

Comment: @Shoe That could maybe be a soloution, but I guess the documents I would generate would look much alike?

Comment: The file name? Because it would contain only a few extra numbers. Plus in your approach, generating twice would result in duplicate file names.

Comment: Yes the file name, I guess I could use something like yyMMdd-fffffff that's actually a good idea, I'm gonna test it out! Thanks :)

Comment: Even tho using the date would be some sort of "fix", it doesn't really answer my issue with comparing a string to a column value.. I'm afraid if I had to use the date the number would be too long. So does anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, I would use `i + 1` as that's uniqueness in it's purest form, but probably you have good reasons so here is a snippet you might want to use:

[Guid.NewGuid().ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)